# Why are all services being changed instead of just the if condition service?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that will be passing in two variables and a csv file to change services on a computer listed in csv file.

the command will be in this format: ex. `start SQLService` or `stop PBIService`

given csv file:

> server,service
>
> server1,SQLService
>
> server2,PBIService
>
> server3,PBIService

```
param($task, $service) #arguments from cmd line input

if($task -eq "start")
{
    Set-Variable -Name "task" -Value "running"
}
elseif($task -eq "stop")
{
    Set-Variable -Name "task" -Value "stopped"
}

if($service -eq "SQLService")
{
    Set-Variable -Name "SQLsvc" -Value "SQLService"
}
elseif($service -eq "PBIService")
{
    Set-Variable -Name "PBIsvc" -Value "PBIService"
}

Import-CSV .\csvfile.csv |
    ForEach {
        if($_.service -eq "SQLService")
        {
            $getService = Get-Service $SQLsvc -ComputerName $_.Server
            $oldstatus = $getService.status
            $getService | 
            Set-Service -Status $task -PassThru |
                Select MachineName, Name, Status, 
                    @{n='OldStatus';e={$oldStatus}}
        }
        elseif($_.Service -eq "PBIService")
        {
            $getService = Get-Service $PBIsvc -ComputerName $_.Server
            $oldstatus = $getService.status
            $getService | 
            Set-Service -Status $task -PassThru |
                Select MachineName, Name, Status, 
                    @{n='OldStatus';e={$oldStatus}}
        }
    } |
    tee output.txt
```

However, when i run this for some reason it affects ALL services...

```
MachineName                    Name                    Status OldStatus
-----------                    ----                    ------ ---------
server1                         SQLService          Running   Running
server2                         PBIService          Running   Running
Set-Service : Service 'Microsoft Monitoring Agent Audit Forwarding (AdtAgent)' cannot be started due to the following
error: Cannot start service AdtAgent on computer 'server3'.
+             Set-Service -Status $task -PassThru |
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Service], Se
   rviceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand

server3 AdtAgent               Stopped ...ed...}
Set-Service : Service 'AllJoyn Router Service (AJRouter)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start
service AJRouter on computer 'server3'.
+             Set-Service -Status $task -PassThru |
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Service], Se
   rviceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand

server3 AJRouter               Stopped ...ed...}
```

Also, why if i command `start SQLService`, PBIService also starts? the condition isnt working properly for some reason...
the only affected server and service in this case should server1 because per if condition, that server has the `service = SQLService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the foreach you don't check what was passed as an argument.

I suggest to only process lines from the csv which match the passed `$Service`

```
Import-CSV .\csvfile.csv | Where-Object Service -eq $Service |
```

Also the script blocks in the if/elseif are identical aside from `$SQLsvc`/`$PBIsvc` which **BOTH** stem from passed $service, so could be merged and directly use $service

Comment: AMAZING! yes thats what i was missing!